# Checking if the first character of an input is a vowel doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program deciding what determiner comes behind the input.

```
#For now, this only works with letters A-D.
MyInput = input("What word do you want to find out if the determiner is a/an?")
Finder = list(MyInput)
if ('a' in Finder):
    print ("Start with an.")
else:
    print ("Start with a.")
```

However, there is a little bug. When I input the word "bad", it says I need to have "an" go before the word. I want it to only say I need to have "an" be before the word when the first letter is A. What's the solution to this problem?

Comment: `in` scans the entire input. You want something like `if Finder[0] == 'a'`. Or better yet, `if Finder[0] in 'aeiou'` (though it won't be perfect, because "an" is chosen based on phonetics - e.g. "an MBA" or "a unicorn")

Comment: You should not convert the input to a list. `MyInput[0]=='a'` suffices. `MyInput.startswith('a')` is even better (in case the input is empty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `in` checks if the character can be found anywhere in the string. When you use "bad" it can. If you are checking the first character use `Finder[0]`

```
MyInput = input("What word do you want to find out if the determiner is a/an?")
Finder = list(MyInput)
if (Finder[0].lower() == 'a'):
    print ("Start with an.")
else:
    print ("Start with a.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question, using [str.startwith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) would be the most clear way to go:

```
# For now, this only works with letters A-D.
my_input = input("What word do you want to find out if the determiner is a/an?")
if my_input.startswith('a'):
    print ("Start with an.")
else:
     print ("Start with a.")
```

Pay attention to the fact you do not need to make a list from a string: strings are iterable, they support `in` and indexing out of the box.

Also note the readability improvements:

- Name variables using snake_case
- Start a comment with a space
- Do not put a conditional into brackets

See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the python style guide for more issues and details about codestyle.

Cheers!